# in-place upgrade native SSRS without the SQL Server portion

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2016, ssrs, upgrade

We have a single server (2012R2) running SQL 2008R2 + reporting services native mode 2008R2

Can the reporting services portion be upgraded alone without the database engine?

Or can the SSRS db be migrated off, SQL instance shut down and then SSRS alone upgraded?

Comment: I believe licensing questions are out of scope for this site.

Comment: @AnthonyGenovese I removed the reference to licensing since it may be out of scope and isn't actually relevant.

Answer (score 1):

> Because of licensing concerns I cannot have SQL Server 2016 running but I still need to upgrade the SSRS to 2016.

They require the same license.  So if you can't run SQL Server 2016, you can't run SSRS 2016.

Comment: Let's forget about the reasoning and just theorize about upgrading SSRS to 2016 while either keeping its own databases on SQL 2008 or an unknown "other" solution.

Comment: It's not supported to run SSRS 2016 with SQL 2008 as the database host.

Comment: well that answers that part. a solution with migrating its databases external may be the only option

Comment: the databases that you pull data from can be 2008. but when you upgrade ssrs, i think it needs to point to a 2016 db for its catalog and such

Answer (score 0):

SSRS can be upgraded seperately to the latest version, I believe without *upgrading* the db engine, but SSRS cant be upgraded without the db engine *running*, as the upgrade will need to make changes to the Reportserver database.

Im not sure what you mean by "migrate off". SSRS requires a running db to work with.

Although another contributor had stated its not supported to run SSRS 2016 on SQL 2008, it *may* work. But just because its possible doesnt mean knowingly entering an unsupported config is a good idea. I'd only do it if i was desperate for an interim solution.

Comment: how can one do your first sentence then? The SQL wizard would only allow both the SSRS and database engine to be checked for upgrade. Unchecking one was greyed out

Comment: @WakeDemons3 did you have latest/seperate SSRS installer? You could also look at PBIRS.